# Filtering a list in a list using linq

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2010

I have a list that I want to filter based on the user input.

So what I've got is this:

```
var fullList = BLogic.GetDataStoreCompaniesForFilterList();
var filterList = fullList
  .Where(w => 
       w.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(filterString.ToLower()) || filterString.Length > 2 && 
       w.Vat.ToLower().Contains(filterString.ToLower()) || w.IndustryLang != null && 
       w.IndustryLang.Where(ww => ww.LanguageId == usrX.LanguageId)
                     .Select(s => s.Name.ToLower())
                     .Contains(filterString.ToLower()) 
   ).ToList();
```

more specifically the last part of the filter query is what's giving me troubles:

```
 w.IndustryLang != null && 
 w.IndustryLang.Where(ww => ww.LanguageId == usrX.LanguageId)
              .Select(s => s.Name.ToLower()).Contains(filterString.ToLower())
```

The full list is list of objects that contains an ID, Name, Vat and a possible list (hence the null check) of IndustryLang objects. Such an IndustryLang object contains an ID, a LanguageID to check which language it is and a Name.

**What I need is to be able to filter on the Name of an IndustryLanguage.**

It probably is just a small mistake but I just don't seem to find it. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Seems like this is trying to constrain to companies that have a language = to usrX.languageId **and** the language name contains the filter string.  This will presumably only happen if the usrX.language contains the filter string, but if a user from language a is asking for a company that has language b, this test will fail.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the entries in fullList for which at least one IndustryLang has a name that contains the filtering condition, replace the 'where' clause by  'any' and include the condition on the IndustryLang object like so:

```
var fullList = BLogic.GetDataStoreCompaniesForFilterList();
var filterList = fullList
  .Where(w => 
       w.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(filterString.ToLower()) || filterString.Length > 2 && 
       w.Vat.ToLower().Contains(filterString.ToLower()) || w.IndustryLang != null && 
       w.IndustryLang.Any(ww => 
           ww.LanguageId == usrX.LanguageId && 
           ww.Name.ToLower().Contains(filterString.ToLower()))
   ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
var fullList = BLogic.GetDataStoreCompaniesForFilterList();
   var filterList = fullList.Where(
    ( w => w.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(filterString.ToLower()) ) || 
    ( filterString.Length > 2 && w.Vat.ToLower().Contains(filterString.ToLower()) ) || 
    ( w.IndustryLang != null && w.IndustryLang.Where(ww => ww.LanguageId == usrX.LanguageId).Select(s => s.Name.ToLower()).Contains(filterString.ToLower()))).ToList();
```

I added some parenthesis.

Comment: 'and' is evaluated before 'or'. Therefore, the parenthesis do not change change the evaluation of the original query.

Comment: It didn't help but it reminded me to add some readability so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misinterpreting your question, and I am new to Linq.  But isn't the list of languages at this point just the list that belongs to that particular company. It seems to me the condition to test for the language to contain your filter string shoul dbe more like so:

```
w.IndustryLang != null &&
w.IndustryLang.Select(s => s.Name.ToLower()).Contains(filterString.ToLower())
```

Comment: Yes each company has a list of languages, in this list of languages I need the correct language (thus the filter for languageId) and the name (translation) needs to correspond to whatever the user entered. So I have two conditions that I need to satifsy and select doesn't do any good.